# How can I un-protect my flash drive?

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I have a flash drive that is showing up with a memory stick icon under my My Computer icon. The computer won't let me open any of the files that are saved on the flash drive. It says that I can't get access due to the fact that it is protected. I don't want the drive to be protected. I need to have access to the files that I saved there. How can I un-protect my flash drive?

Answer (score 3):

Does the USB stick have a hardware (i.e. actual button on the device) "Write Protect Switch"? If this has been acidentally turned on you won't be able to put anything on the drive.

[image]

Comment: That wouldn't stop Katee from opening the files just from saving them.